# Getting 401 Response Code in Jmeter when I tried to see the View Result

Tags: jmeter

Am getting 401 Response code while running my Jmeter script. Here is the sample result, request headers, response body, response headers.

**Sample Result:**
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2022-05-04 20:13:44 IST
Load time:226
Connect Time:0
Latency:226
Size in bytes:591
Sent bytes:876
Headers size in bytes:417
Body size in bytes:174
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:401
Response message:

**Request Headers:**
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Bearer 0rPuk9bYwyE=ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpVeE1pSjkuZXlKemRXSWlPaUpPWVhabFpXNTJaV3h3ZFhKcFFHZHZZWFZrYVhSekxtTnZiU0lzSW1saGRDSTZNVFkxTVRZMk9EZzBNQ3dpWlhod0lqb3hOalV4TnpZNE9EUXdMQ0pxZEdraU9pSmxOREF4WlRZNU1pMWxPVFJtTFRRd01XWXRPR0psTlMwMU1tRXdaR1ptTkdSaFpUVWlMQ0pwYzNNaU9pSXpOamN3TURjMVppMWpZemhpTFRRd1lURXRZakEwT1MxbE4yVXhZMlkxWW1GaFpXVWlmUS5KQjdBOUdyS1I0bWE3N1VieXcySm5xZ3RuQjJJdHR6WVVJWTBZcU13Z1Ztb3AxeXpsNkpzRHF2NDlpVHAwTHhDN1JqNXRPT1dWSnFUeWs5bW5BZTkxUQ==
Referer: http://18.133.204.151/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Origin: http://18.133.204.151
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 2
Host: 18.133.204.151:8080

**Response Body:**
{"timestamp":"2022-05-04T14:43:44.476+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Error -> Unauthorized","path":"/webapp/api/audits/schedule/status/list"}

**Response Headers:**
HTTP/1.1 401
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 04 May 2022 14:43:44 GMT

Can someone please help me in resolving the issue. I tried in many ways and nothing helping me in resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per [401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) status code description:

> 401 Unauthorized

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 401 Unauthorized response status code indicates that the client request has not been completed because **it lacks valid authentication credentials for the requested resource.**

If this [Bearer token](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) is recorded you won't be able to replay the request successfully because the token needs to be **[correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)**. Check out [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables) article for example solution (you might need to amend it to your application specifics)